# Random algorithm with biggest sequence that never repeats

Tags: algorithms, randomness

I am going to attempt to write a random number generator using exisiting randomize algorithms. Can you suggest which algorithm has the biggest sequence that never repeats? I don't care if they are fast or slow.

Comment: Use an appropriate library function. Never try to implement your own random-number generator. You'll make mistakes and the result won't be random.

Comment: while (1) { printf("%d ", i); i++; }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to follow Yuval's advice :), Mersenne Twister algorithm is a good random number generator and has a [quite simple implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister#Pseudocode) (period of $2^{19937}−1$). See Wikipedia page for quick highlights on advantages/disadvantages. There are also many [open source implementations in many programming languages](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/eversions.html).

For technical details and in-deep analysis of the algorithm see [M. Matsumoto's articles that are available on his page](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/ARTICLES/earticles.html).